# Non-constructive $NP$-completeness proof

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np-hard, np

Is there any known $NP$-complete problem which hardness proof is **non-constructive**.

A **constructive** $NP$-completeness proof is a proof that $L_1\leq_p L_2$ by a reduction $r$ and from the argument therein, one can extract two polynomial-time algorithms $f$ and $g$ such that:

> For every instance $x\in L_1$, given a certificate $w_1$ for $x$, we
>   must have that $w_2=f(w_1)$ is a certificate for $r(x)\in L_2$
>
> For every instance $x\in L_1$, given a certificate $w_2$ for $r(x)\in L_2$, we  must have that $w_1=g(w_2)$ is a certificate for $x\in L_1$.

In $NP$-completeness result, that does not describe $f$ and $g$, we can say that it is a **non-constructive proof**. Given a certificate for an instance of $L_1$, *one does not know how to construct a certificate for the corresponding instance of $L_2$ and vice versa*.

**In a sense, the proof only establishes the existence of corresponding certificates.**

*More specifically*, do we have an **existence-only proof** for some $NP$-complete problem?

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this question on CSTheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/14790/does-np-completeness-hardness-have-to-be-constructive/).

Comment: That is the non-constructivity of the existence of a Karp reduction. Here, a Karp reduction must be presented already.

Answer (score 1):

If worst-case one-way permutation exists (which exists iff. $P\neq UP\cap coUP$, proven [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000003000680)), then there exists **inefficient reduction proof** for some $NP$-complete problem.

We denote $\pi$ the one-way permutation above.

Specifically, for each proven $NP$-complete $L$, we can define:

$PERMUTED-WITNESS(L)=\{\pi(x)\mid x\in L\}$

with the certificate for $y\in PERMUTED-WITNESS(L)$ as: $(x,c)$ where $\pi(x)=y$ and $\pi(c)$ is a certificate for $x\in L$ (the "original" certificate). In other words, $c$ is the **pre-image** of the "original" certificate.

So, given a certificate $c'$ for $x\in L$, we cannot efficiently find $c$ (the pre-image of $c'$) for $\pi(x)\in PERMUTED-WITNESS(L)$